# Python function to return list of lists by only swapping the same indices

Tags: python, list, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I have two lists of 5 elements. I want to use itertools or a python code returns a list of 5 elements that consist of all permutations of the list, by only swapping elements of the two lists that have the same index.

For example, if `A = [1,2,3,4,5]` and `B = [a,b,c,d,e]`, I want it to return the following list of lists, C:

Case where no elements of `A` are replaced by `B`:

`[1,2,3,4,5]`

Case where all indices in `A` are replaced by `B`:

`[a,b,c,d,e]`

Cases where only one element in `A` is replaced by the element in `B` with the matching index:

```
[a, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, b, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, c, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, d, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, e]
```

Cases where two elements in `A` are replaced by the element in `B` with the matching index (NOTE: this can be any two elements, the two elements do not have to be adjacent):

`[a, b, 3, 4, 5]`

`[1, b, c, 4, 5]`

`[1, 2, c, d, 5]` …etc…

`[a, 2, 3, 4, e]`

`[1, b, 3, c, 5]` …etc…

Cases where 3 elements are replaced (again, this can be any 3 elements):

`[a, b, c, 4, 5]`

`[1, b, c, d, 5]` …etc…

Cases where 4 elements are replaced (any 4 elements):

`[a, b, c, d, 5]`

`[a, 2, c, d, e]`

`[a, b, c, 4, e]` ...etc...

I thought this would be simple by using itertools, but am running  into an issue in creating this list of lists.

Comment: Are you sure you mean _permutations_ here? Because in your examples, the _order_ of the list elements never changes!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner to do it:

```
from itertools import product

A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = ['a','b','c','d','e']
n = len(A)

out = [[(A if x[i] else B)[i] for i in range(n)] for x in product([0,1], repeat=n)]
```

or (slightly) more pythonic:

```
out = [[(A if y else B)[i] for i,y in enumerate(x)] for x in product([0,1], repeat=n)]
```

Explanation:
`x` spans all possibilities of picking the `i`'th element in either `A` or `B`.

If this is too cryptic for you, then here's the expanded version:

```
out = []
for x in product([0,1], repeat=n):
    l = []
    for i in range(n):
        if x[i]:
            l.append(A[i])
        else:
            l.append(B[i])
    out.append(l)
```

Comment: Cool. But one-liner maybe too `dense` for the uninitiated.... (a simple for-loop can help?)

Comment: Added multi-liner version :)

Comment: Thanks, TIL.  Like one-liner better... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I take your *examples* and ignore the word *permuations*, then what you want is an iterator that does the following: Given two lists of equal length as input, it returns a bunch of lists where the elements of the first list are replaced with the *corresponding* elements of the second list; and the indices of the elements to be replaced are all the length-N *combinations* of possible indices.

Probably something with either a generator function or iterator class...

```py
def get_list_replacement_combinations(list_a, list_b):
  # skipping some checks, like lists having same length
  N = len(list_a)
  for num_replaced_items in range(N+1):
    new_list = list(list_a) # make a copy so we don't mess up the original
    for combination in itertools.combinations(range(N), r=num_replaced_items):
      for index in combination:
        new_list[index] = list_b[index]
      yield new_list
```

I made this up on the fly and didn't test it so there might be bugs but this is definitely the *general* idea. Probably messes up the "length 0" case of replaced items...